# Javascript to read HTTP response codes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have a series of websites that my company manages and I want to create a dashboard that checks to see if each of them are up.  My initial thought was to have a list of websites and run an XMLHTTPRequest against each and list the return code.  I found this code in another post:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );

    alert(xmlHttp.status);
    alert('Hi!');
}
```

However, each time I do that, I get the following error message in Chrome (I used cnn.com as test):

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cnn.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am reading that this is being blocked by SOP, but curiously it works in IE.

Why does it work in IE but not Chrome?  Can it be resolved for Chrome?  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: because ie does not properly enforce cross-site request policies. It makes it quite a dangerous browser to be using.

Comment: I don't believe this is working in IE. Are you able to access the actual response? Alerting the `status` isn't really a good test. Any version of IE that supports `XMLHttpRequest` respects CORS rules or does not allow it at all. In old IE, the only way to do CORS XHR was via XDomainRequest.

Comment: You are wrong.  It certainly works in IE11.  It throws up a message box that reads "200".